# FCM NodeJs firebase-admin: Can't send a data-only message with contentAvailable set to false

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send an FCM data-only message using NodeJs firebase-admin with the new Cloud Messaging V1 API. I would like the message not to be received from my iOS device when the app is closed, but I noticed that Firebase sets the contentAvailable option to true by default.
I'm using the send() method to send the message, and I would prefer not to use the sendToDevice() one because it's deprecated. But using send() I couldn't find a way to set contentAvailable to false.

I tried this code:

```
await this.app.messaging().send({
  token: deviceToken,
  data: { test: 'Hello World' },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        'content-available': 0,
      },
    }
  },
});
```

And I received the error: "Error: Request contains an invalid argument".

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out the correct payload/config?

Comment: @Roundtrip No, I didn't